# Android Studio navigation drawer and activity bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am beginning to code a basic app using android studio and want a **simple way to move from page to page**. Each page has a number of options of where to go next so I think one of these is needed. I have found a description of how to create a navigation drawer on android developers website but it didn't seem to work.

Any help with coding either of these or an alternative would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you place the code which you have done

Comment: Just use android Studio. Add a new activity > gallery > Navigation Drawer Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this links with examples of [navigation drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/), **from navigation drawer you will get options to select**

Try example from above link.

> The navigation drawer is a panel that displays the app’s main
>   navigation options on the left edge of the screen. It is hidden most
>   of the time, but is revealed when the user swipes a finger from the
>   left edge of the screen or, while at the top level of the app, the
>   user touches the app icon in the action bar.

popular applications like Google + already introduced navigation drawer menu in their applications. Following are the navigation drawer menus of multiple apps

Comment: I would also suggest a new example for the navigation drawer using NavigationView. If you need a simple Nav Drawer use NavigationView. If there is customization that is not supported by NavigationView, use a ListView. http://blog.xebia.com/android-design-support-navigationview/

Comment: Good example to start.